# How do I keep the file's permission using `send_file()`?

Tags: python, flask

Let's say I have a file which is named `lhosts`, and it's executable:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 kevin kevin 2.4K Apr 27 21:16 lhosts*
```

And here's my code to send the file using `Flask.send_file()`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from flask import Flask, send_file

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/lhosts')
def lhosts():
    return send_file('scripts/lhosts')


app.run(debug=True)
```

However, when I'm trying to send the file to clients , it doesn't keep the permission. The permission becomes unexecutable:

```
> wget 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/lhosts' --preserve-permissions
--2016-04-27 22:27:39--  http://127.0.0.1:5000/lhosts
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:5000... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 2381 (2.3K) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘lhosts’

lhosts                             100%[================================================================>]   2.33K  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2016-04-27 22:27:39 (76.7 MB/s) - ‘lhosts’ saved [2381/2381]

> ls -lh lhosts 
-rw-r--r-- 1 kevin kevin 2.4K Apr 27 21:16 lhosts
```

How can I keep the file executable?

Comment: How should the HTTP response indicate the permissions? What happens if the server is on GNU/Linux while the client is on Windows?

Comment: if you want to preserve the permission you could add code to your view to zip the file before sending... if the receiver unzips it, it should have the old permission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't directly.  Metadata such as permissions is part of the filesystem, associated with each file but not part of the file's data.

An HTTP repsponse for a download looks just like any other response: some headers and a body.  The body is the binary data of the file, the headers are just the type, encoding, and filename hint, and none of those are actually required.

You could create a scheme to encode the permissions or other metadata in a header, but you would need to write custom code on the receiving end to do something with that.  You'd also need to consider that other things besides your code could download your files, and that permissions differ between Windows and Unix.